# What is this particular song that is played a lot throughout the Chimera Ant arc?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

An example of the song being played is in episode 107, timecode 4:38. This is played a lot throughout this arc.

I am thinking that it could be an unknown track, as I can't find it in the soundtracks when searching through them.

Does anyone know what this song is called?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to the 2011 version of the series, the song you're looking for is called "Mystic Land"

https://youtu.be/YGmACxoYDjE?t=3760

The link I shared should link you to the song in question, as proof of my finding it.

Comment: Video was removed due to copyright claim.